# poedit for long / multiline texts - identifiers vs context

Tags: php, poedit

I'm starting to use poedit for PHP text translations. Now I'm confused what to do with long multiline texts, like a page with Terms and Conditions. I'm having a discussion about this with a colleague.

I see two options:

**Per paragraph or line one poedit field**

This keeps the text inside a `echo _('lorem ipsum');` small.

Disadvantage: if you change the text and need to add lines, you would have to add lines in the code, which is not desirable. You probably wouldn't do this, and then use one identifier to add two paragraphs, which goes against this method.

**All text in one poedit field**

Disadvantage: This would result in a very long identifier. I'm not going to give an example - you know how long they can be. The identifier text could span more than a screen.

**Identifier to describe what should be displayed**

The identifier could be replaced by a short line describing what it is about, like this:

```
<?php _('Terms and conditions: complete text'); ?>
```

Disadvantage: if a new language is added, and this text is not translated, the identifier will show.

Advantage: if paragraphs are added or removed, you can do so without having to change the source code.

Advantage: sometimes one English word is translated into different meanings depending on context, like "bold":

- Font weight: bold - translates to "fett" in German.
- How are you feeling today: bold - translates to "mutig" in German.

NB: you should read this as a form field where you can select what font-weight you want: (1) normal, (2) bold, or (3) italic, not as one text "Font weight: bold".

In these two cases an identifier like "bold-font" and "bold-feeling" would provide context.

**Questions**

How do you handle long texts in poedit? What is best practise?

Answer (score 0):

Gettext is not suitable for long free form texts *at all*. The correct answer is a third one you didn’t mention: **just don’t**. Use e.g. localized text files instead.

To comment on some of your ideas:

> Per paragraph or line one poedit field

Chopping the text into individual lines is an extremely bad idea. It would loose important context.

> Identifier to describe what should be displayed
>   ...
>   Advantage: if paragraphs are added or removed, you can do so without having to change the source code.

Very bad idea as well (generally, not just for long text). If the source (English) text changes, there’s nothing to alert you to do the need to update the translation. Inevitably, the translations *will* get out of sync, undetectably. This is not an “advantage” at all.

There’s a reason why gettext uses source text as the key: it *works*.

> Advantage: sometimes one English word is translated into different meanings depending on context, like "bold":

I don’t see how are different meanings of same words/short texts related to the question at all. That’s handled naturally by gettext with message contexts (`msgctxt`) as [discussed in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Contexts.html).